# onMapReady not being called: Google Map in FrgmentActivity: Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, nullpointerexception, supportmapfragment

I have a FragmentActivity in which i am trying to load the google map. And it implements OnMapReadyCallBack and when i try to inflate the map i get the mapFragment object but the app crashes after getMapAsync is called. Below is my code:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    initializeMap();
    }

    private void initializeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if(mapFragment!=null){
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
            }

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (null== googleMap) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        googleMap = map;
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I tried to degug and i noticed that i am getting the mapFragment object but it never reaches the onMapReady method which makes my googleMap object to be null and the app crashes when any method pertaining to googleMap(e.g. setOnCameraChangeListener) is being called. I have gone through the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) but it doesn't seem to work in my project.

Is there something i might be missing in my project? How should i overcome this error and stop the app to crash.

TIA

EDIT 1:

Below is my map fragment in xml file

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MapsActivity"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Could you show your R.layout.activity_map?

Comment: Check my edit in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint is `getMapAsync` [(asynchronous)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/asynchronous).

`onMapReady` is not called straight away, meaning that `googleMap` won't be set until the method is called.

edit: Make sure you aren't doing methods call on `googleMap` before it is set the map value, i.e. add a check if it is null before running a method on it. Also add the `@Nullable` annotation to `private GoogleMap googleMap;` it will aid in development as Android studio will alert you if you are missing a null check.

Comment: So, how should i rearrange my code to make it work. As i am already initiating the googleMap object inside onMapReady.

Comment: Make sure nothing uses `googleMap` before it is set, remember nothing guarantees when `googleMap` will be not null

Comment: Thanks ryan. Checking for null on googleMap helped me rectify the error. Please check my answer for how i removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

`mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);` means the map will be loaded asynchronous, and if the loading finished a callback to `onMapReady()` will be made.

The following code will probably not work because the map hasn't finished loading yet. You should set up the map inside the `onMapReady()` method, and not inside `initializeMap()`.

```
if (null == googleMap) { // googleMap will still be null here
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: So, how should i rearrange my code to make it work. As i am already initiating the googleMap object inside onMapReady not before that.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I got the solution. I moved the method pertaining to googleMap i.e. setOnCameraChangeListener to onMapReady which was earlier being called in onCreate. googleMap object in onCreate was null which made the app to crash.

Comment: Such an ugly hack!

Comment: True. I struggled on this  for two days and this simple hack solved it

Answer (score -3):

@qwertz you have to set up the map in your oncreate. when getMapAsync is done then the mapreadycallback will then call the onMapReady

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

this works for me

Comment: The question shows that Aashish already has identical code to yours.

Comment: RTQ (READ THE QUESTION) before providing an answer. The OP has clearly stated that he has already implemented the code provided in your post. This post adds no value whatsoever to the discussion.